# assistance on bash script for copying files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, copy

I'm new to linux and to bash programming/scripting as well.
Anyhow, I wanted to make a bash script that will do a few things:

1. will get input on which files to copy
2. will get the dest folder
3. will ask wether to copy or move
4. will do the desired operation
5. will ask at the end if to continue for another action or not

Now, as for parts 2,3,5 I'm ok but part 1 is kinda problematic.
So, here is the script and I hope that you could enlighten me on where I am wrong and why :)

```
#! /bin/bash
#beginning
clear
f=1

Beginning()
{
    echo "HELLO $USER , THIS PROGRAM WILL COPY THE FILES YOU WANT TO YOUR DESIRED DESTINATION DIRECTORY"
    echo -n "please enter the filname/s you want to copy (up to 6 files at a time): ";
    echo
    EnteringF
}

EnteringF()
{
    echo " filename$f : ";
    read cop$f
    Confirm
}

Confirm()
{
    echo "do you wish to copy another file (y/n)?";
    read ans
    if [ "$ans" = "y" ] || [ "$ans" = "Y" ]; then
        f=$[sum=$f+1]
        EnteringF
    elif [ "$ans" = "n" ] || [ "$ans" = "N" ]; then
        Destination
    else
        echo " invalid choice please try again "
        Confirm
    fi
}

Destination()
{
    echo -n "now please enter the destination folder:";
    read dest;
    CopyMove
}
CopyMove() 
{ 
    echo -n "Do you want to copy or move the files/s? please enter c/m? "; 
    read choice; 
    if [ "$choice" = "c" ] || [ "$choice" = "C" ]; then 
        cp "$cop$f" "$dest"; 
        echo "copied successfully" 
        UseAgain 
    elif [ "$choice" = "m" ] || [ "$choice" = "M" ] ; then 
        mv [ "$files" + "$f" ] "$dest"
        echo "moved successfully" 
        UseAgain 
    else 
        echo " invalid choice please try again "; 
        CopyMove 
    fi
}
UseAgain()
{
    echo "Do you want to use the program again y/n?";
    read confirm
    if [ "$confirm" = "y" ] || [ "$confirm" = "Y" ]; then
        Beginning
        UseAgain
    elif [ "$confirm" = "n" ] || [ "$confirm" = "N" ]; then
        End
    else
        echo "invalid choice please try again"; UseAgain
    fi
}
End()
{
    clear
    echo "THANK YOU $USER FOR USING THIS PROGRAM :-)" 
}

Beginning
```

Now my main problem is that no data is recorded to cop variable, and therefore `cp` has nothing to copy.
Maybe I should use some other loop, but I still don't know how to use the others.

Comment: Please indent your code so the structure is easy to see.

Comment: To copy of move, why not just use `mv` and `cp`? what's the point of this script?

Comment: @jkshah User friendly? No tab completion, no readline (ok, he'll use `read -e`), it will fail with filenames containing funny symbols (spaces, newlines, backslashes, leading/trailing), no globs, no options `cp` and `mv` might have, etc. `:)` Yeah, very user-friendly `:)`. Saying `Hello user lololol` is not enough to make it _friendly_.

Answer (score 3):

You'd want to use an array. I've rewritten some parts of your code:

```
#!/bin/bash

clear
f=0
cop=()

abort() {
    echo >&2 "Something went wrong ($@)."
    echo >&2 "Do you have a banana jammed in the keyboard?"
    exit 1
}

Beginning() {
    echo "HELLO $USER , THIS PROGRAM WILL COPY THE FILES YOU WANT TO YOUR DESIRED DESTINATION DIRECTORY"
    echo "please enter the filename/s you want to copy:"
    EnteringF
}

EnteringF() {
    local i=$((${#cop[@]}+1))
    IFS= read -r -e -p " filename$i: " f || abort "EnteringF"
    cop+=( "$f" )
    Confirm
}

Confirm() {
    local ans
    read -e -p "do you wish to copy another file (y/n)? " ans || abort "Confirm"
    if [[ "${ans,,}" = y ]]; then
        EnteringF
    elif [[ "${ans,,}" = "n" ]]; then
        Destination
    else
        echo " invalid choice please try again "
        Confirm
    fi
}

Destination() {
    IFS= read -r -e -p "now please enter the destination folder: " dest || abort "Destination"
    CopyMove
}

CopyMove() { 
    read -r -e -p "Do you want to copy or move the file/s? please enter c/m? " choice || abort "CopyMove"
    if [[ "${choice,,}" = c ]]; then 
        if cp -v -- "${cop[@]}" "$dest"; then
            echo "copied successfully"
        else
            abort "cp"
        fi
        UseAgain 
    elif [[ "${choice,,}" = m ]] ; then 
        if mv -v -- "${cop[@]}" "$dest"; then
            echo "moved successfully"
        else
            abort "mv"
        fi
        UseAgain 
    else 
        echo " invalid choice please try again "
        CopyMove 
    fi
}

UseAgain() {
    read -e "Do you want to use the program again y/n? " confirm || abort "UseAgain"
    if [[ "${confirm,,}" = y ]]; then
        Beginning
        UseAgain
    elif [[ "${confirm,,}" = "n" ]]; then
        End
    else
        echo "invalid choice please try again";
        UseAgain
    fi
}
End() {
    clear
    echo "THANK YOU $USER FOR USING THIS PROGRAM :-)" 
}

Beginning
```

I'm not even sure it works, when I tried to run it I had a black screen with a scary prompt asking me what file I wanted to copy or move. I was expecting a pony or something really cool like a cat playing piano. But no. I didn't know what file I wanted to move, actually. I'm not even sure I wanted to move a file. If I had wanted to move a file, I would have used `mv` directly. I've used a few bashisms for you to dig.

Regarding your question about the variable `cop`, I used an array, so all the problems are gone at once!

More importantly, there's a *huge design flaw* in your program: recursion! it's terrible. You're stacking at each step, never releasing the stack. You should really think your design again! Look: if you call your program `lol_pony_cat`, and if you type this in a terminal:

```
yes '42' | ./lol_pony_cat
```

you'll soon obtain

```
Segmentation fault
```

That's because:

- We start in Beginning
- We go in EnteringF and we're prompt for a file name: we enter `42`
- We go in Confirm and we're prompt for y/n, but we answer an invalid `42`, so
- We go in Confirm and we're prompt for y/n, but we answer an invalid `42`, so
- We go in Confirm and we're prompt for y/n, but we answer an invalid `42`, so
- We go in Confirm and we're prompt for y/n, but we answer an invalid `42`, so
- We go in Confirm and we're prompt for y/n, but we answer an invalid `42`, so
- We go in Confirm and we're prompt for y/n, but we answer an invalid `42`, so
- We go in Confirm and we're prompt for y/n, but we answer an invalid `42`, so
- We go in Confirm and we're prompt for y/n, but we answer an invalid `42`, so
- We go in Confirm and we're prompt for y/n, but we answer an invalid `42`, so
- We go in Confirm and we're prompt for y/n, but we answer an invalid `42`, so
- We go in Confirm and we're prompt for y/n, but we answer an invalid `42`, so
- We go in Confirm and we're prompt for y/n, but we answer an invalid `42`, so
- We go in Confirm and we're prompt for y/n, but we answer an invalid `42`, so
- We go in Confirm and we're prompt for y/n, but we answer an invalid `42`, so
- We go in Confirm and we're prompt for y/n, but we answer an invalid `42`, so
- We go in Confirm and we're prompt for y/n, but we answer an invalid `42`, so
- We go in Confirm and we're prompt for y/n, but we answer an invalid `42`, so...

like this until we reach a stack overflow.

Good luck.

Comment: +1 for *I was expecting a pony or something really cool like a cat playing piano.* LOL!

Comment: thanks! :) didn't check it yet. still, as i said this is my first script (there was 2 before but they are simple) and it was made to understand the writing. now, if you just could explain a bit about what you did because idon't really understand it. i still didn't fully understand the oprators role in writint the script. and as you see i didn't really know about arrays and how to use them. but what i've learned is that i don't need the echo each time. i can use read and therefor save code lines.

Comment: @user2948761 The most important is that you understand the design flaw that leads to stack overflows. Then, read about arrays. Then ask me specific questions about specific operators in the script `:)`